# How should I dynamically add and remove data from a modal in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue component that basically acts a lot like a modal. It's activated when a list item's clicked, and displays the values of some object properties, associated with said item:

```
let myModal = Vue.component( 'my-modal', {
    props: {
        contents: {}, prev: {}, next: {}, show: { type: Boolean }
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            isVisible: this.show,
            videoPost: this.contents
        }
    },
    template:
        `<div class="page-modal" v-show="isVisible">
            <button @click.prevent="close" class="close"></button>
            <div v-html="videoPost.video_embed_code"></div>
            <h2 v-html="videoPost.title.rendered"></h2>
        </div>`,
    methods: {
        close: function () {
            this.isVisible = false
        },
        openWithVideo: function (post) {
            this.videoPost = post
            this.isVisible = true
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        eventHub.$on('showModal', this.openWithVideo)
        this.isVisible = this.show
    },
});
```

Currently it accepts a few props, most importantly `contents`, that's referenced in the data object and output as `videoPost` to be used in the template.

The issue I have, is that it displays a video (embedded in an iframe) and - in its current state - if the video is playing when the user clicks close, the video continues to audibly play.

I tried changing the close method to something like:

```
close: function () {
    this.isVisible = false
    this.videoPost = '' // Added this line
}
```

But this throws an error: "*TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined*" and the modal stays open.

I assume that there must be something wrong with the way I'm displaying the data. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Vue 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @AndrewFrance said is correct.

There is also a different fix; use `v-if` instead of `v-show`. `v-if` removes the component from the DOM instead of just hiding it.

Comment: At some point I was using `v-if`, I can't recall why I changed it to `v-show`. I think maybe I figured show would be a hair's breadth more efficient. This seems to be the simplest solution though.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because your `h2` is expecting an object with a property called `rendered` but you're changing `videoPost` to a string. You could do `this.videoPost = {title: {rendered: ""}, video_embed_code: ""}`.
Or use the `dig` method from Lodash in the binding, or use guards like `videoPost && videoPost.title.rendered` in the binding and set `this.videoPost = {}`.

Comment: Ah of course, makes sense. The only problem however is that with more (nested) properties, this could become quite verbose. I'm not sure what you mean by the guards though - could you elaborate?

Comment: I just mean the use of `&&` to "guard" against null values. With my example above, if you set `videoPost` to `false` then `.title.rendered` will not be called. Or if `videoPost` is `{}` then you can do `videoPost.title && videoPost.title.rendered` I think.